# How to use MVC Controllers for Layours in Sitecore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, sitecore

I'm very new to sitecore and just started learning sitecore over at a dev-course held here in town.
The course is WebForms-focused, and since that's not my "patter of choice" I thought I would see how far I can get using MVC in Sitecore.

However, I have a slight problem. I have noticed how there are Controller Renderers, but and how they are bound to a Controller and such. but how about using a Controller for a Layout?

Lets say I have a layout, that for instance might statically render a menu on the top of the site. Then in this case I would like to avoid having a huge amount of code in my view for rendering the menu-items. Instead I would like to have build and populate a custom view model with the menu items and then simply pass down the model to the view and iterate through my menu items within my model.

But I just cant find a way of how to create a controller for a Layout. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this is possible, you can create a model deriving out of `RenderingModel` class or implement `IRenderingModel` interface and assign it to any MVC rendering or layout in Sitecore. Model object will be instantiated by the Sitecore's `GetModel` pipeline defined in `Sitecore.Mvc.Config` file.

[See Here](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/06/How-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS-Determines-the-Model-Type-for-MVC-Renderings.aspx)

Another way to handle this scenario is to create a Menu view rendering and then insert into a placeholder defined within the layout possibly a header placeholder. This can be statically assigned via standard values.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin is right, thats not possible. Actually, Sitecore uses the layout to recognize a view extension and handle the request with MVC (`TransferMvcLayout` processor in the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline).

You should consider an approach where you add a placeholder in your layout:

```
@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("menu-placeholder")
```

Then add a Menu Controller Rendering to that placeholder. That way you can utilize the rendering cache as well.

Comment: Teresko, when you are ready to a step further check this out http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/06/About-MVC-Helpers-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx for better use of the Sitecore Html helper.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. But you can create a Razor view as layout, which works same as a View Rendering. Just just need to specify the path to the Razor view in the `Path` field and insert a model. In the model you could have simple property, which loads your menu items from whereever you want:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        return MyMenuUtil.LoadMenuItems();
    }
}
```

This avoids lot of code in the Razor view and also in the model.